# Run Flutter Driver Tests On Azure DevOps Pipeline By Flutter Test Job

Tags: flutter, devops, flutterdriver

i want run flutter driver test on devops by flutter test job.
can i run tests on emulator that installed on devops server?
i tried adding flutter command job with this
`flutter drive  --target=test_driver/app.dart` after flutter install job
but it didn't work

Comment: Hi! Yes, you can run integration tests on other machine during CI pipeline. But some settings required. First of all, can you run driver tests on your local machine with the same command `flutter drive  --target=test_driver/app.dart`?

Comment: yes i can run tests in local machine

Comment: then make sure you have flutter and simulator/emulator installed on remote machine. Also make sure that emulator had run before test driver command. Add `flutter doctor -v` before `flutter drive` to your CI config to see if all settings done